# images not showing in angular project

Tags: angular, image

I have added images to assets folder and then
add this like `<img src="../../../assets/graphic.png" alt="">`

on ctrl+click this path it shows that  [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enQ7c.png)
also it doesn't show on app running on browser.

Comment: Have you inspected in the browser to see if it is throwing an error? Inspect, right click on the image link & open in new tab to check if the path you specified is indeed correct.

Comment: path is correct

Comment: in new tab it shows nothing

Answer (score 1):

did you try

```
<img src="assets/graphic.png" alt="">
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular did not accept full path in img src attribute. You have to use image path like this :

```
<img src="assets/graphic.png" alt="this is a image" />
```

If you have a another folder inside the assets folder then you have to use like this :

```
<img src="assets/img/graphic.png" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should reference your assets directory from the web server base -- it prevents issues and allows you to change the base in your index.html file without changing tons of other files for updating the project path.

I use the following which works beautifully:
`<img src="./assets/img/icons/dropdownclosed.svg" />`

Additionally, I have index.html and index.prod.html -- where the  element is modified since the application is served on a subdirectory of a URI.

If you don't need a custom  element -- you can safely ignore the leading ./ on the src url.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
<img src="../assets/images/products/graphic.png" alt="">
```

Comment: **NO**. the "assets" folder is not relative to the folder where your component is. Angular create an index.html and an assets folder (copying your assets folder and bundel all your components). So in general, when we want to use an image they are always in './assets' (we can change this in angular.json). Use ng build, by defect you'll see in "dist folder" one index.html, some bundles js files, one styles.css and a folder "assets". This is the reason to use `./assets`